# How to loop through a string and print each char mips

Tags: mips

Here is my current mips code

```
    .data 
    
buffer: .space 256

    .text 


main:   
    
    li $t1, 1
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 256
    li $v0, 8
    move $t0,$a0
    syscall
    
    la $a0, 256 #reload byte space to primary address
        move $a0,$t0 # primary address = t0 address (load pointer)
        li $v0,4 # print string
        syscall
    
loop:
    lb $a0, ($t1)
    beqz $t1, end
    add $t1, $t1, 1
    j loop
    
end: 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I would like to take input -> print input -> loop through each char -> print char -> if eq 0 jump the end
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here bro beans

```
    .data
buffer: .space 256

    .text
    
main: 
    la $a0, buffer #set buffer space 
    li $a1, 256 #set max buffer size
    li $v0, 8 # get user input
    syscall
    
    la $t0 buffer # set buffer to t0
    
loop:
    lb $t1($t0)
    beqz $t1,end # check if == 0
    
    li $v0, 11 #print the character
    add $a0, $t1, 0
    syscall
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment
    b loop
    
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```